# Send email from Android application

Tags: android

I wanted to know if there is any way we can manipulate the android emulator to use the email clients available on devices to send email from a custom application. Will using third party emulators like the ones available on **[MANYMO](http://www.manymo.com)** make any difference? Thank you.

Comment: I think it will be hard for you to get an answer as this stands... It is hard to see what would be accepted, because I am sure there *is a way* to manipulate the emulator - you need to ask a specific question and explain what you've tried. Check out the FAQ section to see how to ask a good question

Answer (score 0):

The emulator doesn't include any email application for security purposes. In order to send email you need to download any email client (k9mail is a good option) and it will work without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can send an e-mail in Android using the JavaMail API and the Gmail authentication.

Relevant  code for that will be :

```
GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("username@gmail.com", "password");
            sender.sendMail("This is Subject",   
                    "This is Body",   
                    "user@gmail.com",   
                    "user@yahoo.com");
```

See the **[Stack Working Example Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)** .